How do I install python into debian bookworm?
I'm trying to install python into a debian container and for some reason that very simple thing isn't behaving as I expected. The base image that I'm using is mr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bookworm.
My problem is very easily reproduced by issuing
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bookworm sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-full && python"
That does run the installation of python3-full but simply running python at the end fails with

sh: 1: python: not found

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but this isn't an area of expertise for me so any advice would be gratefully received.

python is reserved for Python 2.x, while all Python 3 scripts are expected to use python3.
Try running python3, not python.

DOH! thank you.
